# Can I masturbate in a non pleauring way to release my sexual tension

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, sex, masturbation

Asalamualikum. When I was young I masturbated a few times, I did not know it is haram. When I learned I tried to decrease the amount I masturbated, and alhamdulilah I did, but I still do it sometimes. I am not even sure if masturbation is haram or halal because some people say its haram and some people say its halal. For now until I do more research I will be on the safe side and consider it is haram.

I found a certain way of masturbating, which does not give me alot of pleasure. In addition to this I dont think about women or any sexual thoughts while doing this way. I use this to release my sexual tension when it is extreme. Is this permissible?

I found this answer: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/59623/44507 which says its fine to masturbate in moderation in order to fix an addiction. In the same way is it fine to release sexual tension in extreme cases only?

I am following ways to reduce my sexual desires, but still I want to know if I can do this in an extreme case. If this is haram, is there another way I can cure my sexual tension?

Answer (score 1):

Assalm o Alaikum.
My dear indeed it's a sin and not allowed in Islam.
The Holy prophet P.B.U.H has told us a Dua in such a condition when you want to get rid of a bad habit but find no way... This is very useful dua...
Please try to read this dua more and more...
رب إني مغلوب فانتصر
Rabbi Innee maghloobun fantasir
Jzk